# Texbox que se actualize en tiempo real

Tags: c#

Esto es simple pero no tengo muy en claro como hacerlo:

La idea es hacer un textbox dentro de un formulario en el cual si yo ingreso un numero este aparezca como '?' en el textbox.

Mi idea es hacerlo con el evento KeyPress:

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < 48 || e.KeyChar > 59) && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {

        }
    }
```

¿Alguien me podría decir que debo poner dentro del "if" para que esto funcione?

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo resolví yo mismo, pero igual dejo la solución por si alguien la necesita:

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar > 47 && e.KeyChar < 60)
        {
            e.KeyChar = '?';
        }
    }
```

Con esto podrán ingresar cualquier caracter tranquilamente, pero cuando ingresen números se reemplazarán con '?'.

Comment: Por favor marca tu respuesta con palomita para saber que ya está solucionada. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si estas trabajando en Windows forms, lo habrías podido resolver así :

```
  textBox1.PasswordChar = '?';
```

Saludos,